# SQL INSERT error during Apache Superset init

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, apache-superset

I'm setting up Superset using Python 3.7.7 + Debian 10 in a Docker container and am getting an error when running `superset init`. Expected result: Superset loads example data and initial configuration into my Postgresql 11 database.

The problem looks to be related to Superset's attempt at loading information about its example database. Specifically, some of the values it's attempting to insert are being read as `NoneType`, which sqlalchemy is rejecting because they're not bytes-like. Here are the most relevant portions of the trace:

```
2020-05-20 22:07:50,651:INFO:root:Creating database reference for examples
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography/utils.py", line 36, in _check_byteslike
    memoryview(value)
TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'NoneType'

...
  
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/superset/cli.py", line 51, in init
    utils.get_example_database()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/superset/utils/core.py", line 976, in get_example_database
    return get_or_create_db("examples", db_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/superset/utils/core.py", line 968, in get_or_create_db
    db.session.commit()
...

sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) data must be bytes-like
[SQL: INSERT INTO dbs (created_on, changed_on, verbose_name, database_name, sqlalchemy_uri, password, cache_timeout, select_as_create_table_as, expose_in_sqllab,
 allow_run_async, allow_csv_upload, allow_ctas, allow_dml, force_ctas_schema, allow_multi_schema_metadata_fetch, extra, perm, impersonate_user, created_by_fk, ch
anged_by_fk) VALUES (%(created_on)s, %(changed_on)s, %(verbose_name)s, %(database_name)s, %(sqlalchemy_uri)s, %(password)s, %(cache_timeout)s, %(select_as_create
_table_as)s, %(expose_in_sqllab)s, %(allow_run_async)s, %(allow_csv_upload)s, %(allow_ctas)s, %(allow_dml)s, %(force_ctas_schema)s, %(allow_multi_schema_metadata
_fetch)s, %(extra)s, %(perm)s, %(impersonate_user)s, %(created_by_fk)s, %(changed_by_fk)s) RETURNING dbs.id]
[parameters: [{'database_name': 'examples', 'sqlalchemy_uri': 'postgresql://superset:[redacted]@[redacted]:5432/superset', 'password': '[redacted]', 'perm': None,
 'verbose_name': None, 'cache_timeout': None, 'force_ctas_schema': None}]]
```

Full trace [here](https://gist.github.com/jtotoole/29502d95a855a53b0ab1e7ff60c09dc1). The funny business starts [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/master/superset/utils/core.py#L955), when Superset attempts to record the metadata about its example database but apparently doesn't pass parameters for all the required fields. It attempts to instantiate the `Database` model [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/master/superset/models/core.py#L99).

I get the same error with `superset load_examples`. I don't think it's a database connection issue, as I'm able to access via `psql` and can see that data has been populated in the user table.

Obviously this command typically works fine in other environments, so I'm wondering if perhaps there's some kind of incompatibility in my setup I'm not aware of. Package versions: apache-superset 0.35.2, cryptography 2.7, sqlalchemy 1.3.16, sqlalchemy-utils 0.36.1. My superset_config.py is [here](https://gist.github.com/jtotoole/79b1cc3a8697a9e43a4fd8e7d57ea0bd), and the Dockerfile is a duplicate of [this one](https://github.com/feroult/serverless-superset/blob/master/Dockerfile).

Comment: Hi jtotoole, Can you show us you code? Idealiy can you provide a [mre]

Comment: Thanks EvensF, I'll update the post. In the case of superset the only original code required is the configuration file; mine is [here](https://gist.github.com/jtotoole/79b1cc3a8697a9e43a4fd8e7d57ea0bd). It doesn't deviate much from the standard, and I'm able to connect to the Postgres host + update data in its user table.